# Encountering error while creating new Database in postgres using initdb command

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

When running `bin/initdb demo` I encounter the following error:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "USER_1".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locales
  COLLATE:  en_US.UTF-8
  CTYPE:    en_US.UTF-8
  MESSAGES: en_US.UTF-8
  MONETARY: ur_PK
  NUMERIC:  ur_PK
  TIME:     ur_PK
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory newDB ... initdb: error: could not create directory "newDB": Permission denied
```

Running it as root gives me this error:

```
initdb: error: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

What could be the problem here, would appreciate any help.

Comment: The docs are there for a reason [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html): *initdb must be run as the user that will own the server process, because the server needs to have access to the files and directories that initdb creates. Since the server cannot be run as root, you must not run initdb as root either. (It will in fact refuse to do so.)*

Comment: **Add to question the following information** 1) What OS are you doing this on? 2) How did you install Postgres?

Comment: I am doing it in ubuntu and install it through terminal.

Comment: Are you using the Ubunru packages? If so then  `sudo pg_createcluster` will work. If not you should install the packages. As it happens I just posted two blog posts about this [Install packages](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/06/29/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-1/) and [Package commands](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/07/01/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-2/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run initdb with sudo.

The steps prior to `initdb` should be like so:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/pgsql-12
sudo chown [user] /usr/local/pgsql-12
make install
export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql-12/bin/:$PATH
export PGDATA=/usr/local/pgsql-12/bin/data
```

then, make sure you create the main cluster first before creating others

```
initdb
```

then, you can create others with a name assigned

```
initdb [db name]
```

This should solve that.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to run it with `sudo`. But you need to get permissions before you use `initdb`. Use :

```
sudo chown <username> /path/to/postgres/bin/
```

usually the path is something like

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/
```

You can find by typing `pg_config`. The correct path is in the variable `BINDIR`.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. You do not need to change the ownership on the binaries. You just need to run the `initdb` as the user that owns the `$DATA` directory. Per [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html) that cannot be `root`.

Comment: i encountered the same issue and I solved it by running that command thats why I proposed that

Comment: 1) Yes but you have now changed the binaries to be run by only one user, which means every time you use one of them you will need to be that user. That is a) counter productive and b) not necessary. 2) The issue was running `initdb` as `root` which is explicitly forbidden and the answer does not address that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed your PostgreSQL correctly, the following commands should solve this:

```
bin/initdb demo
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql-12/bin/data -l logfile start
bin/createdb demo
bin/psql demo
```

if it's doesn't work, I suggest you to follow this [Tutorial](https://dev.to/omarsaad/step-by-step-guide-to-install-postgresql-apache-age-on-windows-28gf) to how to install Postgresql and AGE

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `pgsql` folder ownership (pgsql represents the folder you created to install a postgres version), by running the following command:

```
sudo chown new_owner /usr/local/pgsql
```

Note: change the path `/usr/local/pgsql` to postgres folder path on your system.

another note, whenever later you encounter similar issues of `permission denied`, it almost always be solved using either `sudo` before running the command, or by changing the ownership (permissions) to a certain folder.

I hope this helps you